# OpenCSV WriteAll not writing first row of data from resultset

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, opencsv

I'm trying to write my resultset from jdbctemplate query into a csv file using opencsv writeAll.  For some reason, the first row of data isn't written into the csv file.  I looked up the issue and a previous post said that you needed to do a writer.close() and another post mentioned not  using a while (resultset.next()) but I am closing and I am not calling resultset.next().  I'm not sure what's going on and would appreciate if anyone can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I'm testing with Spring Boot H2 db and using Spring JDBCtemplate:

Sql:

```
SELECT testCol, COUNT (*) FROM TEST GROUP BY testCol
```

schema.sql:

```
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST;
CREATE TABLE TEST (
                   testCol VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
                  );
```

data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('01');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('02');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('03');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('04');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('05');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('06');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('07');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('08');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('09');
INSERT INTO TEST(testCol) values ('10');
```

my code:

```
           jdbcTemplate.query(sql, resultSet -> {            
           try {
               cw.writeAll(resultSet, true);
               cw.flush();
               cw.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               logger.error("My Error Message.");
           }
       });
```

And when I run this, testCol with value '01' is always missing.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a little work around to get the first row of data. I used ResultSetMetaData to grab my column count, and since the resultset index starts at 1 therefore I added an int for result set index, used a for loop to grab the result set row value and did a writeNext to add the first row of data to my csv. The code is listed below.  I'm not sure if opencsv writeAll plays nice with the jdbctemplate, I think my cursor is set at the end of the first row so that's why writeAll skips the first row?  I'm not sure so I filed a ticket with opencsv just in case.  I'll share the answer once I get it.  Cheers!

````
CSVWriter cw = new CSVWriter  (new FileWriter("file path")
ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();

        jdbcTemplate.query(sql, resultSet -> {
            try {
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int column_count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                int rsIndex = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < column_count; i++){
                    rsIndex++;
                    valueList.add(resultSet.getString(rsIndex));
                }
                String[] valueArray = new String[valueList.size()];
                valueList.toArray(valueArray);
                cw.writeAll(resultSet, true);
                cw.writeNext(valueArray);
                cw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error with writing resultset to csv.");
            }
        }); 
    ```
````

Comment: yes, the jdbctemplate call was the issue:  https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/support-requests/97/